# Change UITextField and UIButton font name, Color of UIAlertView

Tags: objective-c, uialertview

I want to change my UITextField font name and UIButton (Cancel, OK) color to black of AlertView.
But it doesn't change to what I have expected.

```
- (IBAction)newGroup:(id)sender{
    self.alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"새 그룹의 이름을 입격" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"취소" otherButtonTitles:@"확인", nil];
    self.alertView.tag = new_group;
    self.alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [self.alertView show];
}
```

// Custom font name, color of UIAlertView's control

```
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView)alertView{
  if(alertView.tag == new_group){
    for(UIView *subView in alertView){
       if([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
         UIButton *button = (UIButton *)subView;
         button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
       }else if([subView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]){
         UITextField *textView = (UITextField *)subView;
         textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:30.0f];
       }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

The UITextField font name and font size, UIButton (Cancel, OK) still look the same from the default.

Comment: creat custom alertview .

Comment: Check this
https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview

Comment: Might be help more https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/dlalertview

Comment: Is there any way to just change font name and text color?
Because I don't want spend much with code. Just change font name and text color that all.